# Create a class which dispatches to a random object

Tags: python, random

Suppose I have classes which have a common method (`add`), and I want to create a new class `RandomPair` which would contain a pair of objects of the same class and dispatch `add` to a random one.

E.g.,

```
class C1 (object):
    def __init__ (self, title, plus = True):
        self.title = title
        self.plus = plus
        self.acc = 0

    def add (self, x):
        if self.plus:
            self.acc += x
        else:
            self.acc -= x

    def __str__ (self):
        return "C1(%s,%g)" % (self.title,self.acc)

class C2 (object):
    def __init__ (self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.all = list()

    def add (self, x, pos = None):
        if pos:
            self.all.insert(pos,x)
        else:
            self.all.append(x)

    def __str__ (self):
        return "C2(%s,%s)" % (self.title,self.all)

import random
class RandomPair (object):
    def __init__ (self, klass, title, **kwargs):
        self.objects = [klass(title + "#" + str(i), kwargs) for i in range(2)]

    def add (self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.objects[random.randint(0,1)].add(args,kwargs)

    def __str__ (self):
        return "\n".join([str(o) for o in self.objects])
```

Now, I want to be able to do

```
rp1 = RandomPair(C1,"test")
rp1.add(1)
rp1.add(2)
rp2 = RandomPair(C2,"test")
rp2.add(1)
rp2.add(2, pos=0)
```

but I get

```
TypeError: add() got multiple values for keyword argument 'self'
```

in `self.objects[random.randint(0,1)].add(args,kwargs)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *apply* the args and kwargs, using similar notation as when you defined the arguments. You need to do this in two places; in both `RandomPair.__init__()` and in `RandomPair.add()`:

```
self.objects = [klass(title + "#" + str(i), **kwargs) for i in range(2)]
```

and

```
self.objects[random.randint(0,1)].add(*args, **kwargs)
```

otherwise you are just passing in two arguments, a tuple and a dictionary.

Your next problem is in `C2.add()`; you are using `pos` *if it is empty*; you want to inverse that test. Better still, test explicitly for `None`:

```
def add(self, x, pos=None):
    if pos is None:
        self.all.append(x)
    else:
        self.all.insert(pos,x)
```